# Customization of different shipping cost on each product in cart?

Tags: magento2

I am looking for extension which can deliver same functionality as of

https://www.inwerk-bueromoebel.de

add some products and see each product has different shipping cost . i have researched google a lot but did not find something similar any help on this will be appreciated